# Trying to install Rails on Ruby and getting bash error during installation

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ruby

I get this error when I run

```
\curl -L  https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable:

Command 'bash' is available in '/bin/bash'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
bash: command not found

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 15640)
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what does 'which curl', 'which bash' and 'echo $PATH' says?

Comment: $PATH says this: /usr/bin:/home/jack/local/bin:/home/jack/desktop/extract:/usr/bin
curl version 7.47.1 (newest updated version)

Comment: anyone? I'm really trying to understand how to fix this, but I don't know what to do or the steps to figure it out. I'm new and confused.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `/bin:` (where `bash` lives) on your path. The information on resolving that is in [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Answer (score -1):

Your $PATH has got some issues. Why twice /usr/bin is being mentioned.it needs to be fixed first. 
Essentially /usr/bin should be in the path.

My path entry is

```
echo $PATH
/opt/anaconda2/bin:/opt/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/gradle/bin
```

Note : recently i installed anaconda so it is in front of other default and i should be correcting that.

Also in case you don't have curl installed then try installing it

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: I have curl installed, but I don't understand how to change the $PATH. I don't know what to type or change to make it work.

Comment: @LetsDoIt. It should be easy...just cd to your home directory and look for .bashrc or .profile using vi or gedit and make the changes....once done do a source .bashrc and check the path and try this.